# Firebase Database Rules - Controlling access to collections

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, multi-tenant, firebase-security, nosql

I've been trying to come up with a flat data structure for Firebase Database (as is recommended) and afterwards, a set of rules to control access correctly. My example is trying to demonstrate how you'd lock down/allow access to a db which is multi-tenanted across different organizations.

My first attempt was something like this:

Database structure: https://gist.github.com/peteski22/40b0a79a6854d7bb818919a5262f4a7e

```js
{
    "admins" : {        
        "8UnM6LIiZJYAHVdty6gzdD8oVI42" : true            
    },
    "organizations": {
        "-JiGh_31GA20JabpZBfc" : {
            "name" : "Comp1 Ltd"
        },
        "-JiGh_31GA20JabpZBfd" : {
            "name" : "company2 PLC"
        }
    },            
    "users"  : {
        "8UnM6LIiZJYAHVdty6gzdD8oVI42": {
            "firstName" : "Peter",
            "lastName" : "Piper",
            "email" : "peter.piper@testtest.com",
            "organization" : ""
        },
        "-JiGh_31GA20JabpZBfe" : {
            "firstName" : "Joe",
            "lastName" : "Blogs",
            "email" : "joe.blogs@co1.com",
            "organization" : "-JiGh_31GA20JabpZBfc" 
        },
        "WgnHjk5D8xbuYeA7VDM3ngKwCYV2" : {
            "firstName" : "test",
            "lastName" : "user",
            "email" : "test.user@google.com",
            "organization" : "-JiGh_31GA20JabpZBfd"
        }
    },
    "employees" : {
        "-JiGh_31GA20JabpZBeb" : {
            "organization" : "-JiGh_31GA20JabpZBfc",
            "firstName" : "Johnny",
            "lastName" : "Baggs",
            "email" : "j.baggss@co1.com",
            "employeeNumber" : "ASV123456"           
        },
        "-JiGh_31GA20JabpZBec" : {
            "organization" : "-JiGh_31GA20JabpZBfc",
            "firstName" : "Maheswari",
            "lastName" : "Sanjal",
            "email" : "mahe.sanjal@co1.com",
            "employeeNumber" : "ASV111111"            
        },
        "-JiGh_31GA20JabpZBce" : {
            "organization" : "-JiGh_31GA20JabpZBfd",
            "firstName" : "Fedde",
            "lastName" : "le Grande",
            "email" : "fedde.grande@co2.com",
            "employeeNumber" : "ASV111111"
        }
    }
}
```

Database rules: https://gist.github.com/peteski22/b038d81641c1409cec734d187272eeba

```js
{
    "rules" : {
        "admins" : {
            ".read" : "root.child('admins').hasChild(auth.uid)",
            ".write" : "root.child('admins').hasChild(auth.uid)"
        },
        "users" : {
            "$user" : {
                ".read" : "data.child('organization').val() === root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('organization').val()",
                ".write" : "root.child('admins').hasChild(auth.uid)"
            }            
        },
        "organizations" : {
            "$organization" : {
                ".read" : "$organization === root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('organization').val()",
                ".write" : "root.child('admins').hasChild(auth.uid)"
            }            
        },
        "employees" : {
            "$employee" : {
                ".read" : "data.child('organization').val() === root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('organization').val()",
                ".write" : "data.child('organization').val() === root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('organization').val()"
            }            
        }
    }
}
```

However the problem here seemed to be that I couldn't do something like:

```
[GET] /employees
```

to see a collection of employees that belonged to the same organization as the logged in user.

After much faffing, I read this in the docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#rules_are_not_filters, which I think boils down to 'you're doing it wrong' if you want to get at the data the way I did.

Back to the drawing board, and after reading https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/structuring-data.html / https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data

I made some changes to the db structure and rules:

Attempt #2 structure: https://gist.github.com/peteski22/4593733bf54815393a443dfcd0f34c04

```js
{
    "admins" : {        
        "8UnM6LIiZJYAHVdty6gzdD8oVI42" : true            
    },
    "organizations": {
        "-JiGh_31GA20JabpZBfc" : {
            "name" : "Comp1 Ltd",          
            "users" : {
                "-JiGh_31GA20JabpZBfe" : true,
                "-JiGh_31GA20JabpZBff" : true,
                "-JiGh_31GA20JabpZBea" : true
            },
            "employees" : {
                "-JiGh_31GA20JabpZBeb" : true,
                "-JiGh_31GA20JabpZBec" : true
            }
        },
        "-JiGh_31GA20JabpZBfd" : {
            "name" : "company2 PLC",           
            "users" :{
                "WgnHjk5D8xbuYeA7VDM3ngKwCYV2" : true
            },
            "employees" :{
                "-JiGh_31GA20JabpZBce" : true   
            }
        }
    },
    "users"  : {
        "8UnM6LIiZJYAHVdty6gzdD8oVI42": {
            "firstName" : "Peter",
            "lastName" : "Piper",
            "email" : "peter.piper@testtest.com",
            "organization" : ""
        },
        "-JiGh_31GA20JabpZBfe" : {
            "firstName" : "Joe",
            "lastName" : "Blogs",
            "email" : "joe.blogs@co1.com",
            "organization" : "-JiGh_31GA20JabpZBfc" 
        },
        "-JiGh_31GA20JabpZBff" : {
            "firstName" : "Sally",
            "lastName" : "McSwashle",
            "email" : "sally.mcswashle@co1.com",
            "organization" : "-JiGh_31GA20JabpZBfc"
        },
        "-JiGh_31GA20JabpZBea" : {
            "firstName" : "Eva",
            "lastName" : "Rushtock",
            "email" : "eva.rushtock@payrollings.com",
            "organization" : "-JiGh_31GA20JabpZBfc"
        },
        "WgnHjk5D8xbuYeA7VDM3ngKwCYV2" : {
            "firstName" : "test",
            "lastName" : "user",
            "email" : "test.user@google.com",
            "organization" : "-JiGh_31GA20JabpZBfd"
        }
    },
    "employees" : {
        "-JiGh_31GA20JabpZBeb" : {
            "organization" : "-JiGh_31GA20JabpZBfc",
            "firstName" : "Johnny",
            "lastName" : "Baggs",
            "email" : "j.baggss@financeco.com",
            "employeeNumber" : "ASV123456"
        },
        "-JiGh_31GA20JabpZBec" : {
            "organization" : "-JiGh_31GA20JabpZBfc",
            "firstName" : "Maheswari",
            "lastName" : "Sanjal",
            "email" : "mahe.sanjal@financeco.com",
            "employeeNumber" : "ASV111111"
        },
        "-JiGh_31GA20JabpZBce" : {
            "organization" : "-JiGh_31GA20JabpZBfd",
            "firstName" : "Fedde",
            "lastName" : "le Grande",
            "email" : "fedde.grande@payrollings.com",
            "employeeNumber" : "ASV111111"
        }
    }
}
```

Attempt #2 rules: https://gist.github.com/peteski22/e1be434cd1ea8ec2e630bec6d8aa714f

```js
{
    "rules" : {
        "admins" : {
            ".read" : "root.child('admins').hasChild(auth.uid)",
            ".write" : "root.child('admins').hasChild(auth.uid)"
        },
        "users" : {
            ".indexOn": [ "organization" ],
            "$user" : {
                ".read" : "data.child('organization').val() === root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('organization').val()",
                ".write" : "root.child('admins').hasChild(auth.uid)"
            }            
        },
        "organizations" : {
            ".indexOn": [ "users", "employees" ],
            "$organization" : {
                ".read" : "$organization === root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('organization').val()",
                ".write" : "root.child('admins').hasChild(auth.uid)"
            }            
        },
        "employees" : {
            ".indexOn": [ "organization" ],
            "$employee" : {
                ".read" : "data.child('organization').val() === root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('organization').val()",
                ".write" : "data.child('organization').val() === root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('organization').val()"
            }            
        }
    }
}
```

Now I can keep the data locked down fine in each collection, but the only way to get anything is to *know* the organization ID, get that organization, then get each and every employee by their ID. Although the docs above for structuring data (section: Joining Flattened Data) seem to suggest that it's fine to do this, coming from an OO and SQL background it feels very weird.. which usually means.. 'I'm doing it wrong'.

If anyone has any advice on whether I'm going down the right track, or what to try instead it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the docs and chatting with people in the firebase-community slack, I've come to the conclusion that I was on the right track.

I found using a compiler called "Bolt" (firebase-bolt in npm) extremely useful for generating the rules too.

Here's my structure, bolt rules and compiled JSON rules:

**Structure**

```js
{
    "admins" : {        
        "8UnM6LIiZJYAHVdty6gzdD8oVI42" : true            
    },
    "organizations": {
        "-JiGh_31GA20JabpZBfc" : {
            "name" : "Comp1 Ltd",          
            "users" : {
                "-JiGh_31GA20JabpZBfe" : true,
                "-JiGh_31GA20JabpZBff" : true,
                "-JiGh_31GA20JabpZBea" : true
            },
            "employees" : {
                "-JiGh_31GA20JabpZBeb" : true,
                "-JiGh_31GA20JabpZBec" : true
            }
        },
        "-JiGh_31GA20JabpZBfd" : {
            "name" : "company2 PLC",           
            "users" :{
                "WgnHjk5D8xbuYeA7VDM3ngKwCYV2" : true
            },
            "employees" :{
                "-JiGh_31GA20JabpZBce" : true   
            }
        }
    },
    "users"  : {
        "8UnM6LIiZJYAHVdty6gzdD8oVI42": {
            "firstName" : "Peter",
            "lastName" : "Piper",
            "email" : "peter.piper@testtest.com",
            "organization" : ""
        },
        "-JiGh_31GA20JabpZBfe" : {
            "firstName" : "Joe",
            "lastName" : "Blogs",
            "email" : "joe.blogs@co1.com",
            "organization" : "-JiGh_31GA20JabpZBfc" 
        },
        "-JiGh_31GA20JabpZBff" : {
            "firstName" : "Sally",
            "lastName" : "McSwashle",
            "email" : "sally.mcswashle@co1.com",
            "organization" : "-JiGh_31GA20JabpZBfc"
        },
        "-JiGh_31GA20JabpZBea" : {
            "firstName" : "Eva",
            "lastName" : "Rushtock",
            "email" : "eva.rushtock@payrollings.com",
            "organization" : "-JiGh_31GA20JabpZBfc"
        },
        "WgnHjk5D8xbuYeA7VDM3ngKwCYV2" : {
            "firstName" : "test",
            "lastName" : "user",
            "email" : "test.user@google.com",
            "organization" : "-JiGh_31GA20JabpZBfd"
        }
    },
    "employees" : {
        "-JiGh_31GA20JabpZBeb" : {
            "organization" : "-JiGh_31GA20JabpZBfc",
            "firstName" : "Johnny",
            "lastName" : "Baggs",
            "email" : "j.baggss@financeco.com",
            "employeeNumber" : "ASV123456"
        },
        "-JiGh_31GA20JabpZBec" : {
            "organization" : "-JiGh_31GA20JabpZBfc",
            "firstName" : "Maheswari",
            "lastName" : "Sanjal",
            "email" : "mahe.sanjal@financeco.com",
            "employeeNumber" : "ASV111111"
        },
        "-JiGh_31GA20JabpZBce" : {
            "organization" : "-JiGh_31GA20JabpZBfd",
            "firstName" : "Fedde",
            "lastName" : "le Grande",
            "email" : "fedde.grande@payrollings.com",
            "employeeNumber" : "ASV111111"
        }
    }
}
```

**Bolt Rules**

```js
// **********
// FUNCTIONS
// **********

function isAdmin (auth) {
    return root.admins[auth.uid] != null
}

function isInSameOrganization(auth, orgUid) {
    return root.users[auth.uid].organization === orgUid
}

// **********
// PATHS
// **********

path /admins {
    read() { isAdmin(auth) }
    write() { isAdmin(auth) }
}

path /users {
    index() { ["organization"] }
    write() { isAdmin(auth) }
}

path /users/{id} is User {
    read() { isInSameOrganization(auth, id) || isAdmin(auth) }
}

path /organizations {
    write() { isAdmin(auth) }
}

path /organizations/{id} is Organization {
    read() { isInSameOrganization(auth, id) }
}

path /employees {
    index() { ["organization"] }
    write() { isInSameOrganization(auth, this.organization) || isAdmin(auth) }
}

path /employees/{id} is Employee {
    read() { isInSameOrganization(auth, id) || isAdmin(auth) }
}

// **********
// TYPES
// **********
type OrganizationID extends String {
    validate() { root.organizations[this] != null }
}

type UserID extends String {
    validate() { root.users[this] != null }
}

type EmployeeID extends String {
    // Validate that the user ID exists in the employees node (read rule access should prevent us reading a employees that isn't in our org)
    validate() { root.employees[this] != null }
}

type Email extends String {
    validate() { 
        return this.matches(/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i);
    }
}

type User {
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String
    email: Email,
    organization: OrganizationID
}

type Employee {
    organization: OrganizationID,
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    email: Email,
    employeeNumber: String       
}

type Organization {
    name: String,    
    users: Map<UserID, Boolean> | Null,
    employees: Map<EmployeeID, Boolean> | Null
}
```

**JSON Rules (generated by Bolt)**

```js
{
  "rules": {
    "admins": {
      ".read": "root.child('admins').child(auth.uid).val() != null",
      ".write": "newData.parent().child('admins').child(auth.uid).val() != null"
    },
    "users": {
      ".write": "newData.parent().child('admins').child(auth.uid).val() != null",
      ".indexOn": [
        "organization"
      ],
      "$id": {
        ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['firstName', 'lastName', 'email', 'organization'])",
        "firstName": {
          ".validate": "newData.isString()"
        },
        "lastName": {
          ".validate": "newData.isString()"
        },
        "email": {
          ".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().matches(/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\\\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i)"
        },
        "organization": {
          ".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.parent().parent().parent().child('organizations').child(newData.val()).val() != null"
        },
        "$other": {
          ".validate": "false"
        },
        ".read": "root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('organization').val() == $id || root.child('admins').child(auth.uid).val() != null"
      }
    },
    "organizations": {
      ".write": "newData.parent().child('admins').child(auth.uid).val() != null",
      "$id": {
        ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['name'])",
        "name": {
          ".validate": "newData.isString()"
        },
        "users": {
          "$key1": {
            ".validate": "newData.parent().parent().parent().parent().child('users').child($key1).val() != null && newData.isBoolean()"
          },
          ".validate": "newData.hasChildren()"
        },
        "employees": {
          "$key2": {
            ".validate": "newData.parent().parent().parent().parent().child('employees').child($key2).val() != null && newData.isBoolean()"
          },
          ".validate": "newData.hasChildren()"
        },
        "$other": {
          ".validate": "false"
        },
        ".read": "root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('organization').val() == $id"
      }
    },
    "employees": {
      ".write": "newData.parent().child('users').child(auth.uid).child('organization').val() == newData.child('organization').val() || newData.parent().child('admins').child(auth.uid).val() != null",
      ".indexOn": [
        "organization"
      ],
      "$id": {
        ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['organization', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'email', 'employeeNumber'])",
        "organization": {
          ".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.parent().parent().parent().child('organizations').child(newData.val()).val() != null"
        },
        "firstName": {
          ".validate": "newData.isString()"
        },
        "lastName": {
          ".validate": "newData.isString()"
        },
        "email": {
          ".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().matches(/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\\\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i)"
        },
        "employeeNumber": {
          ".validate": "newData.isString()"
        },
        "$other": {
          ".validate": "false"
        },
        ".read": "root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('organization').val() == $id || root.child('admins').child(auth.uid).val() != null"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm still finding bugs in this, but I think it's showing progress. Just to note that there are some good official & unofficial Firebase videos on Youtube, the docs are fairly decent for the most part, and the firebase-community seems to be friendly. So any new comers like me, you know where to start.